# Which slope is greater: one going very slightly downward, or one going quite steeply downward?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I've been arguing back and forth with someone about this for a while now. It seems to me like a number closer to positive infinity is considered greater, no matter if you are talking about slopes or not. An argument for the steep slope being greater goes like this: it would be quite odd for the slopes two "upper" sides on an equilateral triangle to switch greaterness after the triangle is flipped around the center of the base.

Clarification: I guess the actual question here is this: does "greater slope" equal "more steep" or "closer to going straight up?"

Comment: The sign represents the direction rather than the magnitude - slopes can be steep downward or steep upward depending on which way you are facing.

Comment: My understanding is that "greater" is usually synonymous with "more positive" and "less negative" and that "slope" usually refers to a numeric value which is positive or negative as a line goes upward or downward to the right. Hence I see nothing "odd" about having two slopes "switch greaterness" when the lines defining both slopes are reflected through a vertical axis, because after all, both slopes _switch signs,_ and a positive number is always greater than a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you define as "steep". I would say that the steepness of the slope is mathematically more closely approximated by the *absolute* value of the gradient, not the value itself.

That way, the direction you are traveling in (up or down) does not matter and the line $y=10x$ is equally steep as $y=-10x$ (because if you are going up one it's like going down another)...

Comment: I guess the real question here is whether "greater" equals "more steep."

Comment: I think, "greater" means more of whatever the change the slope measures is, so yes, "greater" == "more steep" (IMHO). At least I can't think of any instances where this wouldn't be the sensible meaning.

Comment: FYI: @dlu is the person I have been "arguing" with this about.